# Overwriting UI elements in Module with requirejs-config.js

Tags: magento2, checkout, requirejs, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to overwrite the necessary UI elements in my module. I for the input fields I need to have the label behind the input.

Now I know how to overwrite these in my theme but I would like to add them to my module to make it easier to install for future projects.

I know that this should be done with the requirejs-config.js but i'm unsure how.

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
            'BB_Checkout/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
        }
    }
},
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html': 'BB_Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/input.html',
        'Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/email.html': 'BB_Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/email.html',
        'Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/password.html': 'BB_Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/form/element/password.html',
        'Magento_Ui/view/frontend/web/templates/form/field.html': 'BB_Checkout/view/frontend/web/templates/form/field.html'
    }
}
 };
```

I currently got this but the part from map: doesn't work. Any idea how I would get this to work? I tried cache cleaning already.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

I also tried this but that doesn't work either. Also tried cleaning browser cache.

```
 map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/input.html': 'BB_Checkout/templates/form/element/input.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/email.html': 'BB_Checkout/templates/form/element/email.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/password.html': 'BB_Checkout/templates/form/element/password.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/field.html': '/BB_Checkout/templates/form/field.html'
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
 map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/input.html': 'templates/form/element/input.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/email.html': 'templates/form/element/email.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/password.html': 'templates/form/element/password.html',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/field.html': 'templates/form/field.html'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah apparently `Magento_Ui/templates is mapped to ui/template` in `Magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\requirejs-config.js`

So after adding `ui/template` it works.